# Cómo obtener este formato de fecha: 2021.01.11T08:55:16.526614Z en delphi

Tags: xml, delphi

Estoy consumiendo un API de facturación electrónica y uno de los datos a ingresar es: `"tIssueDate":"2021.01.11T08:55:16.526614Z"`, el cual es la Fecha de emisión del Documento.

Yo tengo mi fecha en `dd/mm/YYYY` y la hora `HH:MM:SS` pero la `T` la `Z` no sé qué representan ni cómo obtener esa cadena de fecha y hora actual. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un [formato ISO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Fechas_y_horas_conjuntas) usado normalmente en los XML, aunque este tiene una variante: cambia los guiones separadores por puntos.
La T es un indicador/separador de la fecha y la hora, la Z indica hora UTC.

En Delphi la unidad XSBuiltIns trae clases y funciones para trabajar con datos XML.

Puedes usar (añade StrUtils para la función de reemplazo):

```
ReplaceStr(DateTimeToXMLTime(TuVariableDateTime, False), '-', '.');
```

Comment: Creo que la respuesta está genial, pero incompleta, pues parte de la pregunta es que significa la `T` y la `Z` en el formato.

Comment: En el artículo enlazado sobre la ISO lo indica. La T es un indicador/separador de la fecha y la hora, la Z indica hora UTC

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer]. En StackOverflow la práctica, al enlazar información, es incluir las partes esenciales en la respuesta y dejar los enlaces como referencia. Incluso, puedes citar literalmente la fuente, siempre que des la atribución correspondiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, voy a probarlo!